# Value needs to be retained to add to another table

Tags: asp.net

I have a MultiView with 2 views in which there is EmpID.
In the View2: I have Skills (dropDown) as to added of the Employee's that goes into table 
dbo.Emp_Skills

EmpID | SkillID

How do I retain the value of EmpID so that in next view I can add that in other table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it should retain selected value but if it is not doing so, you can manually place the value in `ViewState` object like `ViewState["EmpId"]=EmpId;` and then in next view you can access it like `int empId = Convert.ToInt32( ViewState["EmpId"])`

consider using asp.net wizard control in place of multiview in case of wizard kind of functionality.